# What is a Doctrine_Collection?

Tags: collections, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am getting stuck into the symfony practice tutorial and it is attempting to explain the executeIndex function. Unfortunately it discusses returning a Doctrine_Collection.

I have looked on the net and cannot fathom out what this is, I have seen the documentation for it in lots of places but none of them actually explain what it is in practical terms.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine_Collection is a class of the doctrine ORM framework: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/component-overview/en#collection

Comment: Do records explicitly refer to entries in a database (in my case MySQL)? 

I have to admit to jumping into symfony without actually know what Doctrine is yet - although I have understood its ORM functionality

Comment: Scratch that, the same page explains what they are.

Comment: just a note: Doctrine works in other PHP frameworks too -> e.g. Zend Framework